# i m sending emails with AWS SES and i want to see if the email is opened or not without using SNS is there a way?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, amazon-ses

i m sending the emails using the api and i want to create a separate dashboard apart from the cloudwatch dashboard and i need to get my open rates without using SNS.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Amazon SES [Open and Click Tracking](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/open-and-click-tracking-have-arrived/) feature in conjunction with Amazon SNS.

I'm not sure why you can't use SNS, but in that case you will probably have to implement something yourself, e.g. using your own tracking pixel.

However, as SES natively integrates with SNS, I would highly recommend leveraging the built-in functionality.